# BxSlider кастомная настройка

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть n количество слайдеров, на слайдерах работает auto прокрутка. Нужно что бы auto прокрукта работала по очереди в слайдерах т.е с начала работает auto на 1 слайдере, делает шаги с первого и до последнего и начиная шаг с последнего слайда текущий слайдер перезагружаеться reloadSlider() и активируеться auto прокрутка на следующем слайдере. 
И так работает циклично.
Не могу понять как отследить свойсво auto: true в активном слайдере. Подкскажите как решить задачу.

Все это должно работать **только в режиме автопрокрутки, без нажатий стрелок, и навигации**.

Выбран bxSlider, вот API слайдера: http://bxslider.com/options

Пример: **http://jsfiddle.net/McZ97/4/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея в следующем:

1. при инициализации слайдеров отключаем автовоспроизведение.
2. сразу же после инициализации всех слайдеров включаем листание для первого слайдера
3. на событии onSlideNext() проверяем, не дошло ли листание слайдов до конца. Если дошло, останавливаем воспроизведение текущего слайдера и переходим к следующему.
4. и т.д. по циклу

Пример рабочего кода на [jsfillde](http://jsfiddle.net/McZ97/5/)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду изучать ваш код.

Comment: @gvard1, пожалуйста. Я там var у переменной $slider забыл написать, да и от нее вообще избавиться можно. В общем, там есть чего "причесать" в качестве самостоятельной работы :)